# "Execute stmt" In stored proc -- no Errors but no inserted records

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, error-handling

I had a previous question which was closed... but I managed to work through my errors so hopefully this is more specific question.

In my procedure I generate an insert statement containing 1000 records by concatenating strings over several iterations groups.

```
    ....
    ....    
    SET svalue = CONCAT('(',QUOTE(fHash), ',', QUOTE(cName),  ',', QUOTE(fDescription), ',', QUOTE(fName), ',', QUOTE(fSize), ',', QUOTE(fVersion), ',', QUOTE(pLanguage), ',', QUOTE(pName), ',', QUOTE(pVersion), ',', QUOTE(sig),'),');              
    SET svalues = CONCAT(COALESCE(svalues, ''), svalue);
```

The last  string in the group of iterations does not contain a ",".
In my code I  track the count of records iterated over and the total number of iterations required.

```
SELECT CEILING(CAST(@rec_count as float)/1000) INTO l_icnt;
SET l_cnt = @rec_count  ;
```

@rec_count = SELECT COUNT(*). Each iteration in the loop l_cnt gets subtracted by 1 and every iteration a check occurs:

```
IF CEILING(CAST(l_cnt as float)/1000) = l_icnt - 1 THEN
....
```

If true then the iteration count is also reduced by one in addition to an insert that should occur:

```
  IF .... THEN
    SET svalue = CONCAT('(',QUOTE(fHash), ',', QUOTE(cName),  ',', QUOTE(fDescription), ',', QUOTE(fName), ',', QUOTE(fSize), ',', QUOTE(fVersion), ',', QUOTE(pLanguage), ',', QUOTE(pName), ',', QUOTE(pVersion), ',', QUOTE(sig),')');               
    SET svalues = CONCAT(COALESCE(svalues, ''), svalue);
    
    
    SET @s = CONCAT('INSERT INTO scanfiles.ud_distinctfiles2(fileId, companyName, fileDescription, fileName, fileSize, fileVersion, productLanguage, productName, productVersion, signature) VALUES', svalues);
    call debug_msg(TRUE, CONCAT('insert statement is ', @s));
    prepare stmt from @s;
    execute stmt;
    deallocate prepare stmt;  
    
    SET @s = NULL;
    SET svalues = NULL;
    SET l_icnt = l_icnt -1 ;
  ELSE
  ...
```

My issue is that when the procedure runs, no errors occur however no rows are inserted. Before the insert occurs, I capture the final statement and log that to a table. When I examine the row, I see the statement. I can copy and paste into Workbench and execute it without an issue.

During my previous testing, I found that until I declared an exit handler for sqlexception, things were failing silently:

```
DECLARE exit handler for sqlexception
    BEGIN
        SHOW ERRORS; 
        GET DIAGNOSTICS CONDITION 1
        @p1 = RETURNED_SQLSTATE, @p2 = MESSAGE_TEXT;
            SELECT @p1 as RETURNED_SQLSTATE  , @p2 as MESSAGE_TEXT;
        ROLLBACK;
    END;
    
    
    DECLARE exit handler for sqlwarning
    BEGIN       
        GET DIAGNOSTICS CONDITION 1
        @p1 = RETURNED_SQLSTATE, @p2 = MESSAGE_TEXT;
        SELECT @p1 as RETURNED_SQLSTATE  , @p2 as MESSAGE_TEXT; 
        ROLLBACK;
    END;
```

Am I missing additional declarations to capture all errors? Please note I also tried starting and committing a transaction within the IF block and the results were the same.

Answer (score 0):

Ok it seems that local variables cannot be used with prepared statements. I'm not sure this was explicitly stated in the MySQL documentation but in the MariaDB docs it is. Changing the variable svalues to a user defined variable, the procedure now populates the table.